# SHA512 Compute Hash returns gibberish

Tags: c#, hash, ascii, sha512

I'm trying to write a function to compute the hash value of a string and salt, however it keeps returning what looks to be some encoded value, which is completely unreadable.

Here's my method:

```
public string HashAndSaltString(string stringtohash, string salt)
{
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringtohash + salt);
    System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512 hashed = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed();
    byte[] result = hashed.ComputeHash(data);
    string final = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
    return final;
}
```

And this a sample of what it returns:

```
?mJv?v??a ? ??v??g???s?1t?F?v?6(H????????f.???z??H??(?????
%?O??7J??p4??s=`??&p?u?6?????FX!&????????'???!|?"b??c??
?\w[??2ZB????}??_???P?&^??`r???pw?'???0a???#?!Df??????S+
```

I assume this has something to do with the `GetBytes` and `GetString` parts of the method, encoding it to ASCII?

Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to stuff the bye array into a string? And yes, that's the issue. Just work with the byte array all the way. If you need to transmit it as string, use something like base64.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hash functions usually process their input into a fixed-length chunk of bytes, which isn't made to be human-readable.

The usual way to convert this byte array to a char sequence is to apply base64 to it.

In C# you can do:

```
string final = Convert.ToBase64String(result);
```

to get a string, and:

```
byte[]backToByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(final);
```

to get back a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

SHA just genarate hash-sum for some data, but not encrypt it.
This program show SHA512 hash-sum in hex mode.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "This is random text!";

        var sha = new SHA512Managed();
        byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text));

        Console.WriteLine("Input text: " + text);

        Console.WriteLine("SHA512: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i += 4)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0}{1}{2}{3} ",
                Convert.ToString(hash[i], 16),
                Convert.ToString(hash[i + 1], 16),
                Convert.ToString(hash[i + 2], 16),
                Convert.ToString(hash[i + 3], 16));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

More on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2)